# Will my MacBook Air 2019 support two extra monitors with a 3in1 Thunderbolt to VGA/DVI/HDMI adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I have a MacBook Air 2019 laptop and I got a Dell monitor 24 inches (with VGA and DVI).
I bought a [Thunderbolt video adaptor](https://www.amazon.es/DisplayPort-Thunderbolt-adaptador-Compatible-resoluci%C3%B3n/dp/B01MYZN9P0/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3BCWJAF3U3PWQ&keywords=conector%20dvi%20para%20macbook%20air&qid=1662879639&sprefix=conector%20dvi%20para%20mac%20book%20air%2Caps%2C90&sr=8-5):
[image]

... connected it with a DVI cable and it worked perfectly. I can work with my laptop screen and the monitor.

Now I am going to buy another monitor and I have doubts:

- **Main question**: If I buy a new monitor and connect it via HDMI or VGA... will it work? (Does MacBook 2019 support 2 extra monitors?)
- How can I know if a monitor supports Thunderbolt?
- If I bought a third extra monitor, will all (laptop + 3 extras) work?
- Do I need to have more cables?

Answer (score 1):

The product description says it will not support more than one display at a time. That is pretty much that.

Taking this a bit further we can look into Apple multiple display support and find that Apple (in)famously does not support MST on DisplayPort, meaning no one port is going to support more than one display.

If someone were to plug an external GPU into a Thunderbolt port then the number of displays supported depends on the capability of this added GPU, not that internal to the Mac.  I’ve seen external GPUs that will support three displays but they sell for far more than 13 euro.

With Apple computers it is one display to one port.  Adding a GPU to a port can be considered an exception to this rule but that is because the GPU in the Mac isn’t driving the display any more but the external box.

How can someone know if a display supports Thunderbolt?  You need to examine the spec sheet.  Thunderbolt displays are a bit rare so if that is a feature then it should not be difficult to find as it would be a selling point.

I’m debating on if I should give examples on what is needed to get more displays to work as that might be considered a product endorsement.  If you want three displays from one port then look for an external graphics processor unit, they will look much like a USB-C dock with USB, video, and other ports but it will state in the specification sheet how many displays it will support and cost more than just an average dock.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a full answer, but still this may help:

> If I buy a new monitor and connect it via HDMI or VGA... will it work? (Does MacBook 2019 support 2 extra monitors?)

This is actually two questions: **Yes**, the MBA supports two external displays up to 4K@60Hz. However, I very much doubt, that this adaptor can support two monitors at the same time. It may be able to mirror the same image to both external monitors, but most likely it is unable to extend both screens. I can't be sure though, since the description and its reviews are all in spanish and even DeepL/Google translate fail to translate the important details.

> How can I know if a monitor supports Thunderbolt?

It should be clearly stated that a monitor supports Thunderbolt (TB) somewhere in the descirption (but those are rare, especially with TB 3/4 and USB3/4 nowadays. However, be careful: The TB **2** connector *looks* the same as the mini-DP connector, yet mini-DP is *only* for video transfer, while TB 2 includes the mini-DP protocol amongst others. And to complicate things further: TB 3 and so on have a different connector (the USB-C connector), however TB 3 ≠ USB 3 type C.

> If I bought a third extra monitor, will all (laptop + 3 extras) work?

It does not. Neither does the MBA support three external screen nor will the adaptor be able to handle three monitors at the same time.